# With RPi 3 cannot write to I2C

Tags: raspbian, python, i2c

I have an Adafruit RPI3 running Raspbian version = "8 jessie". I connected a CO2 sensor via I2c and the sensor properly responds to `i2cdetect -y 1` with 0x68 and 0x69.  I believe these are read and write addresses.

Here is my code that compiles with no errors with the Raspian Geany programming editor:

```
import smbus

DEVICE_BUS = 1
DEVICE_ADDR =  0X69
bus = smbus.SMBus(DEVICE_BUS)
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDR, 0X00,0X01)
print("Wrote to bus")
```

When from Geany I execute, a Terminal opens with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smb_bus_write.py", line 9, in <module>
    bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDR, 0X00,0X01)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: I2C  errors are invariably down to a poor, loose, or missing connection.  A description and photo may be useful.  What does the data sheet say the address should be?  I'd expect just the one to be used.  I suspect you are not setting the address properly which would explain why two are seen and the errors.

Comment: BTW there is no such thing as an adafruit RPI3 they may have sold it to you but they don't make Raspberry Pi's

Comment: The connections and sensor response are both correct as verified by i2cdetect -y 1 responding with 0x68 and 0x69. Would you please give me more detail as to the error message: what specifically is reporting the IO error?

Comment: @user53025 The SSCCE and traceback above look as specific as you are going to get to me;  `bus.write_byte_data` from the SSCCE threw the error which in the traceback leads to a file presumably internal to the smbus module.

Comment: However, unless python actually allows you to use `0X` for hexadecimal notation (as opposed to `0x`), that SSCCE is fake.

Comment: @user53025 Without a description of the connections and a photo it's pointless to comment further.